# AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'

Tags: python, discord.py, typeerror

I am trying to make a Discord bot and one of the features is a welcoming from my bot using on_member_join. This is the event:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member, self):
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour(0x95efcc), description=f"Welcome to Rebellions server! You are the{len(list(member.guild.members))}th member!")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed.set_author(name=f"{member.name}", icon_url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{member.guild}", icon_url=f"{member.guild.icon_url}")
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    await welcome_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Although when the bot is working and running and someone joins my server I get this error:

```
[2022-11-07 19:38:10] [ERROR   ] discord.client: Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\stene\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\bot\main.py", line 25, in on_member_join
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'
```

I am running the latest version of discord.py and python.
Thanks!
welcome cog:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import datetime


class WelcomeCog(commands.Cog, name="Welcome"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour(0x95efcc), description=f"Welcome to Rebellions server! You are the{len(list(member.guild.members))}th member!")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar.url)
        embed.set_author(name=member.name, icon_url=member.avatar.url)
        embed.set_footer(text=member.guild)
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

        channel = self.bot.get_channel(1038893507961692290)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(WelcomeCog(bot))
    print("Welcome cog has been loaded successfully!")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In discord.py 2.0 the attribute `Member.avatar_url` got removed and replaced by `Member.avatar`. To access the URL, you should use `member.avatar.url`.

Check out the [migration guide](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#migrating-2-0) for similar instances. Using `pip freeze` you can check which version of discord.py you have installed, but I assume it's 2.x, and probably you followed a tutorial or copied a code example that used discord.py 1.x.

Comment: ive made the whole thing into a cog but its not working, can you help me with that? i get no error or anything, ive edited the post :)

Comment: i actually got an error that goes:
```
[2022-11-09 17:15:29] [ERROR   ] discord.client: Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\stene\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\bot\cogs\welcome.py", line 15, in on_member_join
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar.url)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'url'
```

Comment: got it working actually :)

Answer (score 2):

Following your code you have several errors, which can be corrected in the following code:

> First: `async def on_member_join(member, self):` is an incorrect code.

`self` always comes before any other argument if this event is in a cog file, but still it isn't a required argument so completely remove it. The correct code for this line is `async def on_member_join(member):`

> Second: Make sure you're using the correct event listener.

`@client.event` or `@bot.event` if this is in your Main file, and `@commands.Cog.listener()` if this is in your cog file.

> Third: Please change `(member, self):` to `(member:discord.Member)`

Good luck! :D

Comment: now im getting the error "TypeError: on_member_join() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'" :)

Comment: can you remove ` self ` and try again please?

Comment: then i would have an error where i made "channel" an variable and if i remove the self from there it wouldnt work at all

Comment: How about putting this event in your Main.py file and just use client/bot.get_channel. If you insist on having this line of code in your cog file, then simply create this channel as a variable outside the command, for example channel1 = self.bot.get_channel(), then remove it from the command and leave the await function only

Comment: it worked but now im getting AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'

Comment: remove the f string, embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)

Comment: exact same error

Comment: still no difference

Comment: i will research this issue, but at the moment im out of options, a moment if you would.

Comment: no problems, take your time